# Dagster sensor to check for new records in a table

Tags: python, data-pipeline, dagster

I have 2 tables where 2nd is dependent on 1st. Whenever new records are added in 1st, I want to run a dagster job. I came across sensors but I am not sure if my requirement can be fulfilled using the functionality they provide. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Asset sensors](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/partitions-schedules-sensors/asset-sensors) definitely apply here. If you model your tables as assets, then when the first table is materialized the asset sensor will trigger, which can yield a `RunRequest` to trigger the Dagster job you want to run.

If you don't have control over the code that defines the table, you could also use a normal [sensor](https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/partitions-schedules-sensors/sensors#sensors), and just have it query your table for new records to determine whether to run your Dagster job.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will explore these options.